# Masked Input Plugin with a default value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using  digitalbush's [masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), and I was wondering if there was any way you could add a default value to the masked fields.

I've tried adding it using:

```
 <input id = "date" type="text" value="DD/MM/YYYY" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='DD/MM/YYYY'?'':this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'DD/MM /YYYY':this.value;">
```

but after applying the masking via

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){              
        $("#date").mask("99/99/9999", {placeholder:"#"});
    });      
</script>
```

The default value HTML no longer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tuliomonteazul/EGUcj/

To fix the default value when the page loads I just commented the last call of `checkVal();`.
And to fix the onblur to apply the default value too, I commented the `checkVal();` inside the  `.bind('blur.mask')` and changed the `onblur` function of the input.

I think the plugin's license permits to change his code.

Comment: I was asked to do the same thing but have alternative placeholder text. Here is my fork of the same code http://jsfiddle.net/darronz/ht7hD/