# Masked Input Plugin removes the default value

Tags: jquery, plugins, field, mask

I've been using digitalbush's masked input plugin, and I was wondering if there was any way you could add a default value to the masked fields.

I've tried adding it using:

```
 <input id="date" type="text" value="Example: 01/02/1990" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='Example: 01/02/1990'?'':this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Example: 01/02/1990':this.value;">
```

but after applying the masking via

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){              
        $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
    });      
</script>
```

The default value HTML no longer works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){              
        $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
        $("#date").val("default value");
    });      
</script>
```

Or you can save value before applying the mask, then restore it.

Better solution may be found here
[Masked Input Plugin with a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465832/masked-input-plugin-with-a-default-value)

Comment: where did you know this method ```.val()``` from ? it wasnt written in official docs

Comment: Update: i got, this is a standard jquery method